# What is the Cathay Pacific Marco Polo Club mileage multiplier for Premium Economy?

Tags: air-travel, loyalty-programs, oneworld, cathay-pacific

Here goes with a [Flyertalk type question](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/flyertalk-level-of-questions)....

As a [Cathay Pacific Marco Polo Club](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cpa/en_HK/ffp/mpo/clubmiles) member, I can earn frequent flier miles for Cathay Pacific flights. I can also earn miles for flights taken on any OneWorld carrier (such as BA, Qantas or American Airlines).

Cathay Pacific themselves are a three class airline, having Economy, Business Class and First Class. Likely because of this, their [mileage tables](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cpa/en_HK/ffp/mpo/clubmiles) only supply the class multipliers for those three. As such, I can only look up the expected miles for a flight in one of those three cabins.

However, British Airways (a OneWorld partner) have an extra class, World Traveller Plus (=Premium Economy), which sits between Economy (World Traveller) and Business (Club World).

When flying in WTP on BA, and collecting miles in the CX Marco Polo Club, what multiplier is used? Do you just earn the same miles as in regular economy, or is it a higher amount?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to British Airways' website, [World Traveller Plus falls under fare class T / W / E](http://www.britishairways.com/travel/ecjoinqualifying/public/en_gb).

[On Cathay Pacific's oneworld benefits page](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cpa/en_INTL/ffp/mpo/oneworld), it states that you'll earn:

> Fare classes T, W and E on British Airways earn 110% mileage/sector
>   accrual.

Comment: Ah ha, that's just the page I was looking for but unable to find, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Earlier this year, Cathay Pacific launched their own [Premium Economy Class](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cpa/en_BH/whatonboard/premiumeconomyclass) on selected routes.

As part of this, they've updated their [mileage table](http://www.cathaypacific.com/cpa/en_HK/ffp/mpo/clubmiles) to list premium economy too. As Ankur had previously spotted tucked away, but now in plain view:

```
Premium Economy Class W, R 
You can earn Club miles: 110% of actual miles flown
You can earn Club sectors: 1.1 times the actual sectors flown
```